# jQuery: Call a function twice

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to run a function twice. Once when the page loads, and then again on click. Not sure what I'm doing wrong. Here is my code:

```
$('div').each(function truncate() {
    $(this).addClass('closed').children().slice(0,2).show().find('.truncate').show();
});

$('.truncate').click(function() {

    if ($(this).parent().hasClass('closed')) {
        $(this).parent().removeClass('closed').addClass('open').children().show();
    }

    else if ($(this).parent().hasClass('open')) {
        $(this).parent().removeClass('open').addClass('closed');
        $('div').truncate();
        $(this).show();
    }

});
```

The problem is on line 13 where I call the `truncate();` function a second time. Any idea why it's not working?

**Edit** jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/g6PLu/

Comment: Please add your html in a jsFiddle

Comment: You defined the function inside of another. It can't 'see' that function when you call it on line 13. Define the function outside of both jquery blocks and call it from each.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a named function literal.

The name is only visible within the scope of the function.
Therefore, `truncate` doesn't exist outside of the handler.

Instead, create a normal function and pass it to `each()`:

```
function truncate() { ...}

$('div').each(truncate);
```

Comment: Also he needs to fix the call here >> `$('div').truncate();` to just `truncate()`

Comment: Hmm. Tried that (http://jsfiddle.net/g6PLu/1/) but it doesn't seem to be working. Maybe I have something else wrong, but I was hoping that I would now be able to hide the content by clicking `.truncate` a second time.

Comment: @colindunnn: `truncate()` has no  `this`.  You need to write `$(...).each(truncate)`

Answer (score 0):

What's the error message do you get?

You should create function and then call it as per requirement

Define the function

```
function truncate(){
  $('div').each(function(){

  });
}
```

Then call the function

```
truncate();
```

Comment: If you called this from the click handler for truncate, you would truncate all the sections, not just the clicked section

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to establish, then trigger, a custom event :

```
$('div').on('truncate', function() {
    $(this).......;
}).trigger('truncate');
```

Then, wherever else you need the same action, trigger the event again.

To truncate all divs :

```
$('div').trigger('truncate');
```

Similarly you can truncate just one particular div :

```
$('div#myDiv').trigger('truncate');
```

The only prerequisite is that the custom event handler has been attached, so ...

```
$('p').trigger('truncate');
```

would do nothing because a truncate handler has not been established for `p` elements.

Comment: This seems a better fit for a plugin so OP can just call `$('div').truncate()` as they intended.

Comment: That is certainly another approach Juan - more flexible (available to be applied to any arbitrarily chosen element) but more difficult to write (plugins are hard to write properly).

Answer (score 0):

I know there's already an accepted answer, but I think the best solution would be a plugin http://jsfiddle.net/g6PLu/13/ It seems to be in the spirit of what the OP wants (to be able to call `$('div').truncate`). And makes for much cleaner code

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.truncate = function() {
        this.addClass('closed').children(":not('.truncate')").hide().slice(0,2).show();
    };
    $.fn.untruncate = function() {
        this.removeClass('closed').children().show();
    };                
})(jQuery);

$('div').truncate();

$('.truncate').click(function() {
  var $parent = $(this).parent();
  if ($parent.hasClass('closed')) {
    $parent.untruncate();
  } else {
    $parent.truncate();
  }
});
```